# How to disable default /v3/api-docs definition in springdoc Swagger UI page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have my own OpenAPI specification YAML file which I can able to load in Swagger UI via /openapi-spec.yaml definition but the default /v3/api-docs is still exists. My goal is to disable the default /v3/api-docs and show only /openapi-spec.yaml as default.

Note: I'm using this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

/v3/api-docs:
[image]

/openapi-spec.yaml
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this property in your spring-boot configuration file:

*springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/openapi-spec.yaml*

Comment: Tried it, Still I can load /v3/api-docs and /openapi-spec.yaml not turned into default loader.